# ngClass mysteriously not working with Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a very straightforward ngClass situation that's failing to work, and I'm completely flummoxed as to why:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'sortList' : activeSort }">Some link</a>
```

On the component, activeSort = false, and I can toggle true/false with a button. I've console.log'd to confirm that behavior.

Oddly enough, if I set this, the class takes effect:

```
<a [ngClass]="{'sortList' : true }">Some link</a>
```

So, in essence, it's refusing to recognize a variable I've set on my component, but I have no idea why. Any guesses?

Comment: I have created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-satczv) example where your solution works fine so it must be something else in your code that is causing this problem... I guess you should share more code...

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
[ngClass]="{'aside': true, 'links': message === 'NORMAL', 'links2' : message === 'LIGHT'}"
```